# C# to copy files from one folder to another without duplicates

Tags: c#

Im trying to copy files from "source" folder to my "destination" folder, without duplicates. I cant use destination folder to compare as it will eventually get deleted from there. I had gotten help here to make a batch file

```
Robocopy "source" "destination" "*chr.txt*" "*hdr.txt*" /M
```

that uses attribute to keep track of files copy before. However I need to do this in C# instead. I know theres command to copy

```
System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
```

but not sure how to go about being specific on file name "*chr.txt" and taking care of duplicates.

Comment: You need to use other classes (`System.IO.Directory`, `System.IO.Path`) to list the files of interest and then use this `System.IO.File.Copy` to actually copy it. There might be some windows call (shell based) that might do the copy just like doing it using `Windows Explorer`

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "I cant use destination folder to compare as it will eventually get deleted from there"??? Without visibility of the destination folder how can you know something is not duplicated

Comment: If your files get eventually deleted from the destination folder and you don't want to copy those files from the source ever again, then you should maintain a list (in a text file or a DB), kind of a history of all previously copied files. This is the only sure way to achieve what you need. The bottom line is: you either have to keep the actual files or the history.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to do this in C# instead

```
Process.Start("robocopy", "source destination chr.txt hdr.txt /M");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method I created a while ago that has worked well for me (aside from the checking for duplicates part that I just added and haven't tested). Let me know if any parts of it do not work for what you need.

```
private static void CopyDirectory(string from, string to)
{
    var toFileNames = new DirectoryInfo(to)
        .GetFiles()
        .Select(f => f.Name)
        .ToList();

    var directory = new DirectoryInfo(from);
    var files = directory.GetFiles();
    foreach (var file in files)
        if (!toFileNames.Contains(file.Name))
            file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(to, file.Name));

    var subDirectories = directory.GetDirectories();
    foreach (var subDirectory in subDirectories)
    {
        var newDirectory = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(to, subDirectory.Name));
        CopyDirectory(subDirectory.FullName, newDirectory.FullName);
    }
}
```